# Database for an embedded system

Tags: .net, database, embedded

I'm looking for a very high performance and cheap (hopefully free) database engine to be used on an x86 embedded platform in **Windows CE**. Can anyone give some suggestions?
The important things I'm looking for are:

1. High Performance (for a real-time system)
2. Low cost
3. Usable with Compact .NET framework

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Given your needs the easiest is likely [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx)

1. Performance is pretty good.
2. Free
3. Provides good .NET interoperability

[SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is another option that also meets all of the above. There are numerous tests around that compare the performance of these two under different conditions.